# GridLayout shows everything in the first cell

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, grid-layout

As written in the title, I have this JPanel with  a GridLayout that shows every element above the others. I checked and found that every CityPanel is a 160x185 pixel and the main JPanel (the container) is a 960x556 panel. What's the mistake?

```
public class MapPanel extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private CityPanel[][] cityPanels;

    public MapPanel() {
        super();
        ...
        createLayout();

    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {


        super.paintComponent(g);

        this.setSize(super.getWidth(), super.getHeight());
        mapGrid.setSize(super.getWidth(), super.getHeight());

        for(int i = 0; i < cityPanels.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < cityPanels[i].length; j++) {
                cityPanels[i][j].paintComponent(g);
            }
        }

    }



    private void createLayout() {

        int columns = 6;
        int rows = 6;

        GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(rows, columns);
        this.setLayout(layout);

        cityPanels = new CityPanel[rows][columns]; //CityPanel extends JPanel
        for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < columns; c++) {
                cityPanels[r][c] = new CityPanel();
                add(cityPanels[r][c]);
            }
        }

        for (City city : cities) {
            cityPanels[mapGrid.getRow(city) - 1][mapGrid.getColumn(city) - 1].initialize(city, mapGrid);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Note this is not the random bits of code you think are relevant. It is also not 'all your codes'. Please read the linked documents carefully before preparing an MCVE/SSCCE.

Answer (score 0):

Do not call `paintComponent` recursively on child components. Swing's `paint()` method (triggered by `repaint()`)will automatically call the child `paintComponent` methods for you. The Graphics object passed to the MapPanel's paint method is created with the dimensions and location of the MapPanel. Hence, passing it to the MapPanel's children through `cityPanels[i][j].paintComponent(g)` will cause the child CityPanel to render itself in its parent's location. Assuming the `paintComponent` method in CityPanel is correct, the MapPanel `paintComponent` should just be.

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
}
```

To avoid bogging down the render thread,

```
this.setSize(super.getWidth(), super.getHeight());
mapGrid.setSize(super.getWidth(), super.getHeight());
```

should be included in `createLayout()` if your window does not resize or in a `ComponentListener` if the user can change your window's size.

Comment: `@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
}` that has the exact same effect as ***not*** overriding the method in the first place! So given no actual custom painting is required, it should be completely removed.